# CSS - Long Blocks of text with Input Fields

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web page that is using Bootstrap 3. In this web page, I am displaying some radio buttons. My radio buttons are stylized, so I have an addition element in them. Still, the labels for these radio buttons are quite long. At this time, they render like this:

```
• This is my label. It can be rather long and
wrap to the next line. There could be four or 
even more lines.
```

However, I want them to render like this:

```
• This is my label. It can be rather long and
  wrap to the next line. There could be four or 
  even more lines.
```

Notice how the label text appears indented. It's justified with the rest of the text. In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

```
<div style="width:200px;">
  <label class="my-radio">
     <input data-val="true" id="myChoice" name="myChoice" type="radio" value="1">
     <span class="my-indicator">♥</span>
     This is a long block of block of text that should wrap. But, the second line should be indented        
   </label>
</div>
```

As shown in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/TvvThdhfsa), the label text is not indented. I'm not sure what to do though. I need to be able to click either the radio button itself or the text to select the item. For that reason, I'm not using a table.

Comment: Is it an option to add custom CSS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative margin ([bootply](http://www.bootply.com/VJFS2olgfi)):

CSS

```
.my-radio {
  padding-left:30px;
}
.my-radio input {
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:200px;">
  <label class="my-radio">
     <input data-val="true" id="myChoice" name="myChoice" type="radio" value="1">
     <span class="my-indicator">♥</span>
     This is a long block of block of text that should wrap. But, the second line should be indented

   </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If flex box solution is acceptable, you can try putting the text content inside a container and applying flex box to the parent `label`. Adjust the width as per your requirement.

```css
label {
  width: 320px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
label input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;">
  <label class="my-radio">
    <input data-val="true" id="myChoice" name="myChoice" type="radio" value="1">
    <section>
      <span class="my-indicator">♥</span>
      This is my label. It can be rather long and wrap to the next line. There could be four or even more lines.
    </section>
  </label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.my-radio {
    padding-left: 35px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#myChoice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;">
  <label class="my-radio">
     <input data-val="true" id="myChoice" name="myChoice" type="radio" value="1">
     <span class="my-indicator">♥</span>
     This is a long block of block of text that should wrap. But, the second line should be indented        
   </label>
</div>
```